# div has as extra unwanted space on top inside pre

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why there is an empty space on the top. I haven't applied any styles to it

```html
<pre>
  <div class="codeBlock">
    <ol>
     <li>(function() {</li>
     <li>function $codeBlock() {</li>
     <li>return {};</li>
     </li>}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</pre>
```

[image]

Comment: there is nothing in code. just a list. that class `codeBlock` is also empty @VadimOvchinnikov

Comment: the `ol` and `li`'s have default `margin`. Use `.codeBlock ol, .codeBlock li { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: No, I checked that. I tried that too. can you see the image? that space doesn't belong to the `<ol>`

Comment: `pre` shouldn't contain a `div`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre 

> Permitted content: phrasing content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pre` has `white-space: pre` default style. From [W3Schrools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) about `white-space: pre`:

> Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML

Of course you can move `pre`'s content to one line but not sure this will flexible and maintainable.

So you can change `white-space` CSS property to `normal` or `nowrap` (depending on need of wrapping):

```css
pre {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.codeBlock ol, li {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <div class="codeBlock">
    <ol>
     <li>(function() {</li>
     <li>function $codeBlock() {</li>
     <li>return {};</li>
     </li>}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</pre>
```

If you want to return `white-space` behaviour for `ol` you can also set

```
.codeBlock ol { white-space: pre }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so heres the thing. pre takes every character and interpret it in it's display, that mean it will litterally "show" a carriage return. Try to remove the spaces. Lets say you you twig, apply {% spaceless %}. If you use something else, use the proper function, but if you do it manually, do like i just did in the example below :) Cheers

```html
<pre><div class="codeBlock"><ol><li>(function() {</li><li>function $codeBlock() {</li><li>return {};</li><li>}</li></ol></div></pre>
```

Comment: Also, if you just need to display code on a webpage, I would recomand to use a specialised javascript library like Prism.js or highlightjs

Comment: yes. thank you that fixed it. I never thought of that. can I do anything else to fix this because while pretty-print HTML everything changes back. any other thing

Comment: I don't want to use libraries for this purpose. My requirement is not that big

Comment: Do you use php?

Comment: Ok so there's only one way then. In css, but the problem is that you need to be very specific. Yeah you can use white-space:nowrap. But after, you'll still have to target your ul, ol, blockquote, etc. etc. Its a good solution, but not necessary flexible.